# Replace carrier name with Wi-Fi SSID in notification drawer

Tags: cyanogenmod, notification-bar, xposed-framework

I've seen a couple of ROMs/devices which, when connected to a Wi-Fi network, show that network's name (SSID) in place of the carrier name in the notification pulldown. Is there a way to achieve that with an Xposed Framework module on CyanogenMod 11?